# Database Driven Page Content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

I am trying to make a facebook style wall on my website. The goal is to insert form data, validate all forms as required, and store this data into a database. Simultaneously and separately I want all data stored in this database to be posted into a div that acts as the facebook wall.

I seem to have accomplished storing the data from the form. I can also retrieve all data in the database except it only does it when I submit the form. Which means no page content unless the user submits a post.

How can I populate my page with rows from my database when a user opens the page or before?

Please help!

Here is my php which stores and prints data when the html form is submitted.

```
<?php
  // Create connection
  $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $sql="INSERT INTO test (school, confession)
  VALUES
  ('$_POST[school]','$_POST[confession]')";

  if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
  echo "1 record added";

  //  print $_POST['college']."-<br />".$_POST['confession'];
  $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM test");

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    echo "#" . $row['ID'] . " " . $row['confession'];
    echo "<br>" . "@" .$row['school'];
    echo "<br>" . "<br>";
  }

  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Here is my JS which posts to a div called content.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#subform").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      // do other stuff for a valid form
      $.post('test.php', $("#subform").serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#content').html(data);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for using mysqli, i respect that you're trying to make something complex while you're learning. But yeah, you need to use mysql SELECT to retrieve data from db, you can read about it if you google it.

Comment: you need to use `setInterval` to reload the content on regular intervals. you also need to clear the html of #content after posting, then reload the div via $.get

Comment: oh and your insert code is not gonna work, you need to do this
('".$_POST[school]."','".$_POST[confession]."')

Comment: I can't answer my own question.. But I solved it. Thanks for the replies. I just called the php on load.

     'code'$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#subform").validate({
   submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do other stuff for a valid form
    $.post('test.php', $("#subform").serialize(), function(data) {
     $('#subform').html(data);
    });
   }
  });
 });'code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to load data on mouse scroll like:

```
  //approx this
$(document).ready(function () {
    var flg='1';
    $(window).scroll(function () {
    console.log($(document).scrollTop());
    if ($(document).scrollTop() >299){
        if(flg=='1')
            {
        $.post( 'link to server side code', function( data ) {
            $('#morefrom').html(data.htmls);
        },'json');
         flg='0';
            }
    }
  });});
```

This way you can load data on a specific mouse scroll value(like if a user gets on the bottom of the page you load new rows)
[scrollTop docs](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Comment: Thanks! I like this and will use it.

Comment: In my php how can I load only a specific number of entries each time it loads instead of just loading the entire database? I know I will use a loop but this is just my first time using php.

Comment: you can use limit 10 for selecting 10 rows only. Also you can array_slice(){http://bd1.php.net/array_slice}  to slice the recieved array. Accept my answer?

Comment: Sure ill accept it. Can you point me to an example of this on the web?

Comment: http://www.citibd.com/Category.aspx?category=%E0%A6%9C%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%A4%E0%A7%80%E0%A7%9F&id=1 This is a rough example where you scroll to the end of the page to see the last row adding up

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **JavaScript Timer** which will ticks after certain interval and load your Data, plus you must have to write a function that will just fetch the Data  in your     `test.php` file

```
function dataLoader()
{
   //load Data with GET Request $.get(. . . );
}

dataLoader();
setInterval(dataLoader, 1000);
```

or the **Second** option will to be use jquery Timer Library to achieve performance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies I solved the problem. I just called the php on load.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#subform").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            // do other stuff for a valid form
            $.post('test.php', $("#subform").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#subform').html(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```